# Void pointer to class error

Tags: c++, class, pointers

```
class Hero
{
public:
    Hero();
    virtual int useAbility(){}
    virtual int basicAttack(){}
    int getHitPoints();
    int getManaPoints();
    void setHitPoints(int x);
    void setManaPoints(int x);
protected:
    unsigned int hitPoints;
    unsigned int manaPoints;
private:
    friend void printHero();
```

};

```
class Mage : public Hero
{
public:
    Mage();
    int useAbility();
    int basicAttack();
    std::string getClassName();
protected:
private:
    std::string className;
```

};

Same for Warrior

```
int input;
void *actor;
cin >> input;
if(input == 1) actor = new Warrior;
if(input == 2) actor = new Mage;
printHero(actor.getClassName(),actor.getHitPoints(),actor.getManaPoints());
```

So i declare the pointer 'actor' , and I want it to become a pointer to a class, but apparently it does not work.

I get this error

> request for member 'getClassName' in 'actor', which is of non-class type 'void*'

Comment: There are no methods on a `void *`.

Comment: IMHO - When a programmer is using void pointers they are usually doing something wrong

Comment: Look up abstract classes

Comment: You need to inherit `Warrior` and `Mage` from a same class (with at least 1 virtual function), then change `actor` type to pointer to that class.

Comment: It is built like that, i tried it, it doesnt work either

Comment: I fixed it, thx all for your help!

Comment: @Mihai update your answer and close the thread

Answer (score -1):

Warrior and Mage have the parent class person.

you want to do:

```
person *actor;
```

Comment: 1) There is no way for you to know if `Warrior`/`Mage` classes have a parent class (or even how those classes are defined), from the example given. 2) Example (with explanation) needs to be more in-depth.

Comment: I already tried that, but the methods are not in the parent class

Comment: class Mage : public Hero (same for Warrior)